# Comparing path names, and the path may be non-existent

Tags: linux, path, linux-kernel, kernel, kernel-module

I am trying to write a file blacklist kernel module for school. In this module I need to compare paths names from intercepted system calls(which can be relative or absolute) to a list of blacklisted path names(which are all absolute).  These paths may or may not exist at the time the module is loaded.  I have been told to look at the system calls in /fs/open.c for getting a struct path. I tried user_path but it returns an error if the path is non-existent.  Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Also, I am on the 3.0.4 kernel. I have the strings for blacklisted path names read from the file (yeah I know its bad but this is the way they want it done) and inserted into the internal list. I am just stuck on the comparison of the blacklist path name and path name/file name passed to the intercepted system calls.